# Is the double slit pattern a standing wave?

Tags: waves, interference, double-slit-experiment

This question is about terminology. The double slit pattern has nodal lines and antinodal lines, and therefore resembles a standing wave. However, the antinodal lines within the double slit pattern resemble travelling waves. Do the terms *standing wave* and *travelling wave* have a definition, and if so, are those definitions mutually exclusive?

-- Edit, for clarification: Naively, I would tend to think that only a Chladni pattern is a true standing wave, because its antinodal areas are standing waves, not travelling waves.

[[image: image derived from wikimedia commons image][1]]

*image derived from a [wikimedia commons image](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:%E0%B8%8A%E0%B9%88%E0%B8%AD%E0%B8%87%E0%B9%81%E0%B8%84%E0%B8%9A%E0%B8%84%E0%B8%B9%E0%B9%88.gif)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the interference pattern produced by two slits (or, equivalently, two oscillators with the same frequency that are in phase with each other) is a type of two dimensional standing wave.

The nodes, where the amplitude of the combined wave is zero, lie along lines where the difference in the distance from the two slits is an odd number of half-wavelengths. Along these lines the two waves are $180^o$ out of phase so they cancel each other out.

There are also lines of anti-nodes, where the difference in the distance from the two slits is a whole number of wavelengths. Along these lines the two waves are exactly in phase, so the amplitude of the combined wave is the sum of the amplitudes of the individual waves. The mid-line exactly half way between the two slits is one example of a line of anti-nodes.

Comment: Do you imply that _standing wave_ is fully synonymous with _interference pattern_?

Comment: @jkien No, interference pattern is a more general term and can apply to waves with different wavelengths. But if two waves are *coherent* and their sources are stationary w.r.t. the medium in which the waves travel then their interference pattern is a standing wave.